# Remote port forwarded SSH considered as an invalid user accessing from 127.0.0.1

Tags: macos, ubuntu, unix, ssh, portforwarding

I am trying to connect to a server which already established a remote ssh connection to my client by running the following on server:

```
ssh -R :8080:localhost:22 -p 22 clientUser@clientIP
```

when I try to connect to the server by running the following on the client side:

```
ssh -p 8080 localhost
```

I am getting asked for a password as:

```
clientUser@localhost's password:
```

both connections should be able to establish via public key (the remote port forwarding ssh already can do this with no problem.)

furthermore in /var/log/auth.log on server shows:

```
Invalid user clientUser from 127.0.0.1 port 39768
```

which suggests that the server sees this as kind of a loopback connection?

the client OS is MacOSX Mojave and the server side is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

If I try to remote forward the connection from the client to any port other than 22 on the server I am getting

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I appreciate your kind help!

Comment: The "Invalid user" message and request for password imply that there's no user named `clientUser` on the server.  Since that is what you are specifying, is that not what you're expecting?  You might want `ssh -p 8080 serverUser@localhost`?

Comment: The "Connection closed" message when you try to forward to a port other than 22 implies that whatever is listening on that port is not expecting an ssh_exchange.  What port are you trying to forward to and what do you expect to be listening there?

Comment: you are right. thanks a lot for the clarification. `ssh -p 8080 serverUser@localhost` works now.

Comment: I believe the problem with other ports would be also the fact that they are not expecging the ssh connection but the main problem was solved thanks to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to Chris in comments.

the problem was I had to

```
ssh -p 8080 serverUser@localhost
```

by default

```
ssh -p 8080 localhost
```

is the same as

```
ssh -p 8080 ${USER}@localhost
```

and uses the current user from the environment. This will results in an invalid user message by the server.